# Add table efficiently from android to php server?

Tags: php, android, sql

I am adding data from an android app to a php server. As of now, I am basically uploading one line at a time from my android app so it needs to make a connection for each line in a table. This does not seem very efficient. How can I change my code so that it makes one connection and uploads all data in the table at once? My method looks something like this:

```
public Boolean upLoad(){    

       //tells how many entries successfully uploaded
       int count = 0;

        Uri uri = ProviderMetaData.TableMetaData.CONTENT_URI;
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.0.5/xampp/fields.php"); 
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
        String[] projection = new String[]{ProviderMetaData.TableMetaData._ID,
                ProviderMetaData.TableMetaData.FIELD1, 
                ProviderMetaData.TableMetaData.FIELD2,
                ProviderMetaData.TableMetaData.FIELD3,
                }
    Activity a = (Activity)this.mContext;
        Cursor cur = a.managedQuery(uri,projection,null,null,
                ProviderMetaData.TableMetaData.);

           String field1;
           String field2;
           String field3;
           Boolean success = false;
           Boolean nofailure = true;
           Scanner sc;

   if (cur.moveToFirst()) //fix this. cur.moveToFirst problem
   {       


       int field1Column = cur.getColumnIndex(ProviderMetaData.TableMetaData.FIELD1);
       int field2Column = cur.getColumnIndex(ProviderMetaData.TableMetaData.FIELD2);
       int field3Column = cur.getColumnIndex(ProviderMetaData.TableMetaData.FIELD3);



       do {
           field1 = cur.getString(field2Column);
           field2 = cur.getString(field2Column);
           field3 = cur.getString(field3Column);
            try { 
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3); 
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("field1", field1)); 
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("field2", field2)); 
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("field3", field3 ));              
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); 
                count++;
                success = true;


            } 
            catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                 Log.d("uploadCursorData","could not make connection");
                 success = false;
                 nofailure = false;
            } 
            catch (IOException e) { 

                 Log.d("uploadCursorData","Some other kind of exception" + e.toString());
                 success = false;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                success = false;
                nofailure = false;
            }
       } while (cur.moveToNext());

       Log.d("upLoadCursorData", "The number of entries successfully oploaded are " + count);


       }

   Log.d("Success", "was this successful?: " + success);
   return nofailure;

   }
```

On the server side I just collect and process each line in the table using $_POST['field#']. How do I upload everything in the table at once?

Comment: no, still uploading using a loop that is breaking and making a connection to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your data to JSON format, post it to the server, then decode the JSON on the server and save it. This is the most common way to do this.

Comment: do you know how to do this in Java/Android? I was only able to create a 1D JSON object

Comment: I do not know Java, but google search showed me http://json.org/java/ which seems to be a good resource.